# The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'captchaValid'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, recaptcha

I am trying to allow google reCaptcha in my registration process and I have gotten it to display. However when I try to run through my registration to test it I get the following error:[image]

My understanding of the error is that captchaValid is not in the `RegisterViewModel`, this makes no sense since here it is defined in my RegisterViewModel:

```
[Required]
public bool? captchaValid { get; set; }
```

and here in my controller I have:

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model, string message, bool captchaValid)
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Required and nullable  ?

Comment: @Shyju if you look at my code for my `RegisterViewModel` I have already set it to required...right?

Comment: Your `Register` method takes a `bool`, but your RegisterViewModel property is a `nullable bool`. These are effectively two different types, and you can't pass one off as the other.

Comment: I see what I did there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your http post action method has a parameter called `captchaValid` of `bool` type. So when you submit the form, There **should be** one form field (in the request body) or query string key(if the form submit is of GET type) item matching this name for routing to work. The route engine looks for the request data/querystring and based on the parameters, it redirects to the corresponding

But your view model already has a property called `captchaValid`. So remove that from your action method parameter list and everything should work.(Model binder will map the posted value for this form field to the property of your view model)

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model, string message)
{
  // to do : return something
}
```

Now When you submit the form, it will hit the http post action method and  if you are not providing the value for `captchaValid` field from your form ,your model validation fails with the message "The captchaValid field is required" (because it is marked as a required field)

Answer (score 2):

You can either:

1. Change your `captchaValid` property to a `bool`
2. Change the signature of the `Register` method to take a `bool?`
3. Decide on a default value if the property is null, and then call your `Register` method with that value:

.

```
bool defaultCaptchaValue = false;

Register(model, message, captchaValid.GetValueOrDefault(defaultCaptchaValue));
```

Comment: `bool convertedCaptchaValue = captchaValid.GetValueOrDefault(defaultCaptchaValue);` is arguably a little more clear.

Comment: Agreed! Updated the answer. Thanks @BradleyUffner

Comment: Similar to webforms, that bool will need to be declared as a public protected bool in the beginning of the Account Controller class, right? I can't just add that directly before the register method

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea. If you know you want a specific default value, then you don't need a bool to store it...you could just pass it in to the `GetValueOrDefault` method when calling `Register`: `Register(model, message, captchaValid.GetValueOrDefault(false));`